# Pandas string slice returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
Ref   Net   
C1    1- A:VCC 
C2    2- A:VDD 
C3    3- A:GND
```

I would like to remove `1- A:`,`2- A:` and `3- A:` from the `Net` column:

```
Ref   Net  
C1    VCC  
C2    VDD  
C3    GND
```

I tried this command:
`df.Net = df.Net.str.slice(df.Net.str.find('A:'))`

But then the `Net` column became `NaN`:

```
print(df.Net)
---------
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
```

The slice command returns the proper values:

```
print(df.Net.str.find('A:'))
------
0  3
1  3
2  3
```

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [539]: df.Net = df.Net.str.split(':').str[-1]

In [540]: df
Out[540]: 
  Ref  Net
0  C1  VCC
1  C2  VDD
2  C3  GND
```

Comment: What does `str[-1]` do here? If I want only "V" left and strip "CC" out, can I tweak str[-1] to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume, net Series has type str. Perhaps you should try something like :

```
df['result'] = df['Net'].apply(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[-1])
```

`apply(str)` is optional if type is str.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ref':['C1', 'C2'], 'Net':['1- A:VCC', '2- A:VDD']})
df['Net'] = df['Net'].str.replace(r'\d- \w:', '')
```

**Output:**

```
  Ref    Net
0  C1  VCC
1  C2  VDD
```